# I want to asyncronous blink a led during wifi connection micropython board

Tags: python, python-asyncio, micropython

I have two co-routines. I start led blinking and wifi connection, but after wifi connection is complete i want to stop led blinking function.

Led blinking function:

```
async def blink: 
  while True:
   led.on()
   await uasyncio.sleep(seconds) 
   led.off()
   await uasyncio.sleep(seconds)
```

Comment: Instead of `True` use a state variable.

Comment: yes, surely it is the simplest solution, but is there a solution to delete a co-routine from another co-routine?

Answer (score 1):

use an [asyncio.Event](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Event) e.g.

```py
async def main():
    wifi_connected = asyncio.Event()

    async def connect_to_wifi():
        led.on()
        await ...  # do connection stuff
        wifi_connected.set()

    async def wait_for_connection():
        await wifi_connected.wait()
        led.off()

    await asyncio.gather(connect_to_wifi(), wait_for_connection())

asyncio.run(main())
```